# MySQL count across multiple tables and get single value

Tags: mysql, select, count, inner-join, union-all

Imagine:
    t1 = 1
    t2 = 3
    t3 = 5

I need to run individual selects on each table, and report the count in a single amount, ie:

```
 select * 
   from (select count(*) from t1)
          + (select count(*) from t2)
          + (select count(*) from t3);
```

My end result should be = 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close; you can write:

```
 select (select count(*) from t1)
        + (select count(*) from t2)
        + (select count(*) from t3)
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    (select count(*) from t1)
    + (select count(*) from t2)
    + (select count(*) from t3);
```